# How to persuade MS Word that .NET is one word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm writing a text about my work in .NET and the word ".NET" makes Word think that the dot is the end of a sentence. How can I persuade MS Word that .NET is one word?

PS: I know I can use dotNET but I don't like it.

Comment: Word 2007 isn't complaining about .NET for me. Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: Is it complainint about the inferred blanking, e.g. "Programs in .NET" should be "Programs in. NET"?

Comment: MS Word 2007 but in Czech language. It may be the problem. Thanks for info!

Comment: Andreas: yes, exactly.

Comment: have you already tried adding the word to your user dictionary?

See http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/microsoftword2007/a/dictionary2007.htm

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Can you just ignore the error and leave it as it is?

Comment: @tobeannounced: Yes, I can but I may lose some corrections suggestions from Word thanks to the word .NET.

Comment: Try disabling autocorrect.