# How to tell Word "para." is an abbreviation and not the end of a sentence?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, spell-check

In Word 2013 on my system, the sentence `He turned to pg. 2 and was surprised.` spell-checks cleanly.  However, the sentence `He turned to para. 2 and was surprised.` (changing `pg.` to `para.`) flags a grammar error:

[image: screenshot]

Yeah, I know, I'm a dinosaur — I still put two spaces after a period. ;)

The same happens for `pgs.` in place of `pg.`  Word apparently recognizes that `pg.` doesn't end a sentence.  Is there any way to tell Word that `para.` *also* doesn't end a sentence?

I tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/327189/269989) (adding to the AutoCorrect list) but without success.  [This question](https://superuser.com/q/166059/269989) (`.NET` as one word) seems related but is unanswered.  I get the same results with either `para` or `para.` listed in `CUSTOM.DIC`, and I get the same results if neither is listed.  No spelling errors, just the space-after-sentence grammar error.

**Edit:** Grammar-check settings:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it really does understand that pg. doesn't end a sentence? Because my Word 2007 doesn't care whether periods come after abbreviations (even widely used) or not and complains about wrong number of spaces if have that check on. They could have changed it since then, but I'd double check just to be sure.

Comment: Well, I pasted your texts (exact copy and paste for the 2 sentences into a new document) and my Word 2013 did not complain.

Comment: Thank you both for checking!  @Sanny, also en-US?  Do you have 2 spaces required after periods in the grammar settings?  I edited the question to add the settings I'm using.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo Good question.  I checked the text `The pg. is good.  It is his page.  It is his pg.  This is a new sentence.  Pg. 5 is good.  pg. 5 is good.`, with two spaces between sentences.  With my current settings, 2013 didn't flag any errors in that text.  Apparently `pg.` can occur anywhere, even at the end of a sentence, plus it can be at the beginning or in the middle of a sentence without triggering end-of-sentence checking!

Comment: My subscription upgraded to Word 2016 and the feature you mentioned has been removed. However, it seems this new Word doesn't care about spaces after fullstops (regardless being used to end sentences or for abbreviations) and switching en-UK with en-US shows no difference.

Comment: @Sanny thanks for the update.  Good to know upgrading is a workaround. :)

Comment: If things work well, write an answer here to close your question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a workaround, for now I am going to global-replace "para." to "paragraph" before spell-checking, and then change it back afterwards.

Readers, note @Sanny's comment above — it looks like this isn't an issue with Word 2016.

Marking as answer in order to clear the decks — anyone with a better answer, please post it!